# CoovaChilli redirect to a new page on successfull login, to display user account balance

Tags: shell, coovachilli

I'm working on a CoovaChilli project at work. I have experience with PHP but I'm very new to shell scripting. Though I Googled and read Coova support blogs they don't seem to give directions for very beginners.

What I'm trying to do is on a successful login, redirect the user to a new page.
Sadly I have no idea what I'm doing, but what I did was I tried to follow exactly the same path they used, to direct user to signup page on  button click...

They had 2 main different files extensions linked for signup process

newuser.chi

newuser.chi.save

newuser_form.tmpl

signup.chi

so i created the same file extentions for my new file

intermediate.tmpl(in which I think I have to display the user's balance)

intermediate.chi

In login page for submit button i added my new file...

```
<!--
  --  The login form
-->

<div id="login-form">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Username</td>
  <td><INPUT NAME="username" VALUE="$FORM_username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Password</td>
  <td><INPUT NAME="password" VALUE="$FORM_password" TYPE="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" nowrap align="center">
    <input type="button" name="signup" value="Sign Up" onClick="window.location='/www/newuser.chi'">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" onClick="window.location='/www/intermediate.chi'">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**intermediate.tmpl**:

```
<div id="intermediate-form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Reload</td>
                <td><input type="button" name="reload" value="Reload" onClick="window.location='/www/recharge.chi'"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Balance</td>
                <td>**---I Need To Display Customer's Balance Here---**</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" nowrap align="center">
                    <input type="button" name="continue" value="Continue" onClick="window.location='http://www.earlierSuccessfullPage.com'">
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
```

**intermediate.chi**:

```
<? # -*- mode: shell-script -*-
# Copyright (C) 2009-2011 Coova Technologies, LLC. <support@coova.com>
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

. ./config.sh
http_header
header "<meta></meta>"
uamfile "login 1"
intermediate    /* <= I followed what they did in signup */
footer
?>
```

in **config-local.sh** i added this new function...

```
intermediate(){
    form "intermediate.chi" "$(uamfile intermediate 1)"
}
```

I cant get it to redirect successfully to an empty page on button click let alone display user's balance on it.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? For example, what part of the manual did you find that was most relevant? You've given us your existing code, but readers are generally keen that prior research is demonstrated rather than just claimed.

Comment: @halfer Hi, thank for the response. I updated the question with more details. I tried to copy exactly what they did in a redirection, since I hardly have any idea what the code exactly says... :(

Comment: Much better, thanks - I don't know this technology, but that at least has a lot more detail to assist readers.

Comment: Oops! My Bad, Thanks. I appreciate your help.